# How does deallocation of stack frame takes place without the %rbp register?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, x86-64

I have read that using a base register to keep track of stack frames is not really necessary. I don't understand how does the compiler achieve this, does it store the stack frame size somewhere and read it and adds it to the %rsp?

Comment: Compilers do still make stack frames with %rbp in functions that contain C99 variable length arrays or other things like that.  You don't need stack frames when the frame size is a compile-time constant, in which case it's only stored as an immediate operand to `add`.  Look at any compiler output, e.g. on http://gcc.godbolt.org/.  Stack frame size is also stored in `.eh_frame` metadata so exception handlers (and debuggers) can unwind the stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That isn't usually necessary either, as long as you're in either of two cases:

1. `rsp` is changed only by a known amount
2. `rsp` is never changed at all (you could say this is a known amount, and the amount is 0)

Typically in x64 code, `rsp` is only changed in the prologue, epilogue, and implicitly with calls/returns. Any temporary space is allocated up front and addressed by indexing into the stack frame (mostly as usual, except the offset is from `rsp` instead of a base pointer - that doesn't make any difference if `rsp` doesn't change), not through pushes and pops. In that case it is easy to recover the old `rsp`, just add the same thing that was subtracted in the prologue.

Or, and this applies especially to linux where there is a redzone, for many leaf functions you can get away with not changing `rsp` at all. In this case you may not even need a prologue or epilogue, and just have a bunch of normal code followed by `ret`.

Obviously `alloca` (and other constructs that allocate a variable amount of stack space) breaks this, and a frame pointer will be used again.